# Install later version of docker-engine stuck on Travis build

Tags: docker, installation, automated-tests, build-automation, travis-ci

Because I need a newer version of docker-compose, I also need a newer version of docker-engine. I tried:

```
before_install:
  - sudo apt-get install -qq docker-engine
```

However, the build gets stuck at a prompt:

```
Configuration file '/etc/default/docker'
 ==> Modified (by you or by a script) since installation.
 ==> Package distributor has shipped an updated version.
   What would you like to do about it ?  Your options are:
    Y or I  : install the package maintainer's version
    N or O  : keep your currently-installed version
      D     : show the differences between the versions
      Z     : start a shell to examine the situation
 The default action is to keep your current version.
*** docker (Y/I/N/O/D/Z) [default=N] ?
```

How do I make it keep the old version without blocking? (Or should I accept the new version? I'm guessing Travis CI is doing some stuff to it...)

I tried `sudo apt-get remove -qq docker-engine` first, which didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Try `--yes` or `--no`. See which options Travis uses for installing packages from apt-get.

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue; `sudo apt-get install --yes -qq docker-engine` only skips the "would you like to install" prompt, not the config file prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using the right Travis CI environment, the [Trusty beta environment](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/trusty-ci-environment/).

Then see the Travis docs for [updating your Docker Compose here](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/docker/#Using-Docker-Compose).